# Django annotate constant datetime MariaDB

Tags: django

Given a queryset `qs` of model `A` I would like to annotate it with a constant datetime. E.g.,

```
# models.py
# ---------
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    pass

# test.py
# -------
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db import models
from myapp.models import A

A.objects.create()
qs = A.objects.all()
qs.annotate(now=Value(datetime.utcnow(), models.DateTimeField()))
# Throws: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

The above code works using `sqlite` but fails with `MariaDB (5.5.52)`. Any idea how to get this to work on `MariaDB`?

```
django==1.11.3
python==3.4.5
```

#### Traceback

```
/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1451: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField (unbound) received a naive datetime (2018-05-24 21:34:04.070362) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 101, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 289, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 834, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 819, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 239, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 285, in make_aware
    return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 236, in localize
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Comment: I'm facing a similiar issue, have you ever solved this?

Comment: @Patrick I think I gave up on this after running into several other bugs with Django annotations that were only fixed in Django 2.0+ and not my version (1.11)